# Can I use the Room Persistence Library for Java desktop applications?

Tags: java, android-room

Is it possible to use the [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) from Google's Android Architecture Components in a java desktop application or in other words – as I haven't found anything on that – which things needed to be done and how complicated would that be?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know that too, as it is not an uncommon requirement, to perform data exchange between Android and desktop.

Comment: I also want to know

Comment: I also want to know

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. When creating a Room database, you need to supply an android `Context`, but that does not exist outside of android projects. I would suggest trying an ORM like [exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/exposed) or [ktorm](https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm) instead